# Tools for replaying _all_ HTTP traffic

Tags: http, load-testing

I intend to log all production HTTP requests to be able to do load testing and analysis on that data later on. The log replaying software I have seen so far only seem capable of replaying GETs. Are there tools out there that can take a file in a specific format and run that against a given instance?

The only thing I have seen so far is a tool called [Sprockets](http://patrick.net/sprocket/rwt.html), which does not seem to have been used by other people than the author since 2008 ... 
EDIT: After testing it, it also seems a bit buggy :/

Comment: NGROK is also a modern alternative. https://ngrok.com “I want to securely expose a local web server to the internet and capture all traffic for detailed inspection and replay."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gor](http://github.com/buger/gor) might be worth the try. It supports forwarding requests to multiple different instances or dumping the traffic to file for later replay. It also supports adjusting the number of requests per second.

This way you can replay traffic from production to staging and dev environments, always ensuring that your code works, while ensuring that you are not totally swamping your development servers.

[image: Traffic overview]

Answer (score 0):

Why dump in table storage? You may want to consider dump in standard pcap format and then use http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/ to replay traffic.

Comment: Because TS is cheap storage and supports easy filtering/retrieval. Save and forget. And HTTP requests seem to fit the data model easily. tcpreplay seems to be too detailed. It is just too overwhelming, and I will have to do so much filtering and fiddling with the data it seems before I can get to the HTTP data.

Comment: It seems way too complicated to just take the logs from one machine and replay them against another.

Comment: It also seems that tcpreplay does not support the scenario I described: Sending Traffic to a Server

"Problem:
You have a pcap capture and would like to replay that traffic at another server.

Solution:
First, this will only work with ICMP and UDP traffic. Tcpreplay doesn't support sending TCP traffic at a server because it doesn't synchronize Syn/Ack numbers in the TCP stream."

Sending me on a wild goose chase certainly makes downvoting seem very attractive.